# Issues with Spring 3 and Google App engine

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine

This is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

and this is my dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">
    <!-- JSR-303 support will be detected on classpath and enabled automatically -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

And I have an annotated Controller class:

```
@Controller
public class MainController {
    @RequestMapping("/test")
    public ModelAndView testHandler(){
          ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
            mav.setViewName("testView");
            mav.addObject("message", "test");
            return mav;
    }
}
```

The project compiles without errors, but when I run it and hit http://.aggengine.com//test I get a 404. Is my mapping wrong or my URI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you forgot to create a `<bean>` for your controller.

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

Just enables support for reading the annotations off of beans when they're created.

E.g. To register your controller:

```
<bean id="mainController" class="my.package.MainController"/>
```

Alternatively you could enable automatic classpath scanning, but that can cause performance issues on appengine as it's slow (and will happen every time your app cold-starts)

To enable classpath scanning, add the context namespace to your `<beans>` and add:

```
 <context:component-scan base-package="my.package"/>
```